# C++ Question about variables : add an integer inside a string

Tags: c++, variables

I have this code for a window with two labels (label and lblclicount) and one button (butprint)
It is a small tutorial i found on youtube i just add some text arround the variable that count the numbre of clic the user makes
.
I just want to learn C++ I know how to do this with VisualBasic.
Here is the link of the tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gi3VuB--vjU and bellow i try to explain the things i don't really understand but it works.

```
void MainWindow::on_butprint_clicked()
{
    static int nbrclic = 0;
    QString strnbrclic, texte;
    nbrclic++;
    ui->label->setText("Hello World");
    strnbrclic.sprintf("%i", nbrclic);
    texte= "Vous avez cliqué " + strnbrclic + " fois.";
    ui->lblcliccount->setText(texte);

}
```

I was thinking i can do
`ui->lblclicount->setText("Vous avez cliqué " + nbrclic + " fois.");` (but it doesn't work.)

instead of having to do

```
strnbrclic.sprintf("%i", nbrclic);
texte= "Vous avez cliqué " + strnbrclic + " fois.";
```

I think i understand that **strnbrclic.sprintf("%i", nbrclic);** convert the integer nbrclic in a string and after i add my text and the variable value of nbrclic in a new one ith the line

```
texte= "Vous avez cliqué " + strnbrclic + " fois.";
```

I'm french and i'm sorry if my question is not simple to understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert an int to a string you can simply do `to_string(your_int_here)`

Alternatively, just use `<iostream>`.
`to_string` is part of the standard `<string>` library, so either declare you're `using namespace std` or use it as `std::to_string`

If you're using `QString` as part of the *Qt Core* library, then to get it into the standard `std::string` format you can call `your_variable_here.toStdString()` as described in their documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

Comment: Thank you for this answer i'm goint to study the namespace ; it seems to be important in C++.

Answer (score 1):

SetText() takes a **string** as an argument. In the example provided by you it works because in the first place there is a sprintf instruction:

`strnbrclic.sprintf("%i", nbrclic);`

Which effectively writes nbrclic (an integer value) into a string strnbrclic

Then you have:

`texte= "Vous avez cliqué " + strnbrclic + " fois.";`

Which [concatenates](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_strings_concat.asp) three strings (strnbrclic is an int written into a string), so there is no type error.

What you tried to do in your code (the one which does not work), was to concatenate two strings **and integer value** which is not possible. For your example to work, you need to write the `nbrclic` into a string.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Now i understand that in C++ i can concatenate only the same type of value.

Comment: Much obliged mate. Does your code work yet?